# finding the sum of series

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $a$ and $p$ are relatively coprime integers, then is there any efficient way of calculating the following:
$(\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{a^k}) \% p$ ?
I'm interested in the cases when $0 \leq n ≤ 2147483647$ and $2 ≤ p ≤ 2147483647$.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{a^k} = \frac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1}$.   If $n$ is prime then the Euler-Fermat theorem simplifies things a little: $a^{n+1} \equiv a^2 \mod n$. Then your answer becomes $\frac{a^2-1}{a-1} = a+1 \mod n$.  But in other situations I'm not sure you get such a nice answer.

Comment: thanks..but here p is prime and co-prime to a and not n , still no standard formula?

Comment: You're getting an answer mod $n$, but the question asked for the sum mod $p$.

Comment: @pranay, there's no formula for $a^{n+1}\pmod p$ better than $a^{n+1}\pmod p$ (unless there is some relation between $p$ and $n$), so do you think there will be a better formula than $(a^{n+1}-1)/(a-1)$ for your question?

Comment: no. but besides using exponentiation by squaring, can we use modular exponentiation here ?